# позиционирование div

Tags: css, html, позиционирование

Здравствуйте.
В ощем возникла проблема с div`ами, парюсь уже несколько дней.

Сначала, что необходимо, затем чего получается и что нет.

Для background есть рисунок разделенный на 3 части для 3-х div`ов
На всю эту композицию должен быть наложен текст ( на все 3, а не только на среднюю часть )
Левая и правая часть имеют фиксированные размеры, средняя должна расстягиваться по ширине текста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получется выстроить их в одну линию, получается наложить текст,
а вот совместить одно с другим не выходит.

Если налаживаю текст на все три, то средний не растягивается, это и понятно, absolute выкидывает из общего потока.
Если убрать div с текстом, а сам текст поместить в div id="center", то тогда текст естественно не ложится на два крайних.

В id=(left, right, center) прописанны только свойства для background.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute;">
         ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute;">
      <div id="left" ></div>
      <div id="right"></div>
      <div id="center"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Если есть решение только на css, помгите, если нет то отпишите, что это невозможно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий пример:

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
.dd {
  line-height: 348px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 150px;
  font-size: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dd>span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dd:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 348px;
  width: 324px;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/9DnegYW.png") left top;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.dd:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 348px;
  width: 324px;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/2tQFf8E.png") right top;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.dd>i {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/V0OSUzF.png") repeat-x center 43%;
  height: 348px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 324px;
  right: 324px;
}
```

```html
<div class='dd'>
  <span>test test test test</span><i></i>
</div>
<div class='dd'>
  <span>test test test test test test test</span><i></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, теперь все работает, но только когда подставляю свои картинки, то "средний фон" залазит на два крайних и получается вот так
http://i.imgur.com/JmJITac.jpg

Comment: Сами картинки 

http://i.imgur.com/9DnegYW.png
http://i.imgur.com/V0OSUzF.png
http://i.imgur.com/2tQFf8E.png

Comment: @Sergey Я изменил пример, но он использует белый фон, прозрачность надо сохранить?

Comment: Да, прозрачность необходима

Comment: @Sergey Тогда так

Comment: Crantisz, Спасибо огромное, подогнал под свои размеры, все работает. Сам бы точно в ближайшем будущем к такому решению не пришел.